# How to get the referer for unathenticated URL in spring security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

In spring security Config file we have handled the unauthenticated urls must go through login page.
.loginPage("/login/forward")

when it goes to this particular handler Controller, I wanna know for which unauthenticated URLS it has come to this controller.

For example if I am trying to access http://localhost/ab/getAbc and if it is not an authenticated URL , so spring security will redirect to .loginPageMethod for all unauthorized URL. Now when it is going to /login/forward I am unable to get the Url page which user tried to access at first time.

Comment: Why do you want to know the URL?

Comment: I have two different environment there so lets first one is /ab/getAbc and the second one is /bc/getBcd, Now for first one I wanna redirect to error page and for the second one I wanna put a push message. I am able to the variable using getSession().setAttributes but I dont wanna use the session object, how to achieve this?

Comment: You could inject the request and get the URL from the request.